# Count Table Record Value and Assign Count Value as Variable in PHP mySQL

Tags: php, html, sql, count

I have a database with area details like state name, district, city, area size, ...

Now I would like to count a districts value from state name and assign that value to some variable for showing html page.

```
Example: The tamil nadu state includes total of 30 districts.
```

Query for showing states list,

```
$qry = "SELECT DISTINCT state_Name FROM area_info ORDER BY state_Name";
```

How to do this.. anyone please help me..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should try this, surely will solve your query.

```
$qry = "SELECT state_name, COUNT(district) As TotalData FROM area_info GROUP BY state_name";
```

Comment: @Dinesh Dinu, try this solution

Comment: thanks. im not showing this count value in my html table. i will use this as html <p> tag. For an example The tamil nadu state includes total of 30 districts.  In that example tamil nadu is not a mandatory.  total of 30 districts is a dynamic count value. my html code will be 'The tamil nadu state includes total of <?php echo $district_Cont; ?> districts.'

Comment: Modified my answer, check it now.

Comment: Count value will return you the number of districts.

Comment: @DineshDiNu Check it now

Comment: @DineshDiNu No worries, keep going.

Answer (score 2):

Try this Query:

```
SELECT count(district) 
FROM area_info 
GROUP BY state_Name
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this

```
$qry = "SELECT DISTINCT state_Name, COUNT(*) AS district  FROM area_info Group BY state_Name" ;
```

Comment: @Vickrant  Example: The tamil nadu state includes total of 30 districts. State name is required. In addition Your answer is correct.

Answer (score 2):

To get the count of the record, you can use below query

```
$totaldist = "SELECT count(DISTINCT) state_Name FROM area_info GROUP BY state_Name";
```

and then to assign this variable you can write like :

```
echo "The tamil nadu state includes total of $totaldist districts.";
```

Comment: Guys.. Thanks for the replay.. but not works for me. I would to count total districts from my db and im willing to store that value to $district_Cont. when i add <?php echo $district_Cont; ?> the count value should be replaced.

Answer (score 1):

List with State name's and number of districts in it:

```
SELECT state_Name, COUNT(district)
FROM area_info
GROUP BY state_Name;
```